# How to list directories with particular depth?

Tags: directory

I want to list only those directories which are a particular depth from current directory.
Let's say depth=2

The directories listed can be:

```
./abc/abc
./xyz/xyz
```

If depth is 3

```
./mvd/123/abc
```

etc.

Comment: Does symbolic links to directories elsewhere count?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes it does

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`find` allows you to specify both a minimal and maximal recursion depth:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the depth is 2. You can use

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2
```

Here `type d` option will list only directory.

`maxdepth 2 and mindepth 2` will give all the directories and files with exact  depth of 2.